# Popen.communicate() throws UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, subprocess

I have this code:

```
def __executeCommand(self, command: str, input: str = None) -> str:
    p = sub.Popen(command, stdout=sub.PIPE, stderr=sub.PIPE, stdin=sub.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
    p.stdin.write(input)
    output, error = p.communicate()
    if (len(errors) > 0):
        raise EnvironmentError("Could not generate the key: " + error)
    elif (p.returncode != 0):
        raise EnvironmentError("Could not generate the key. Return Value: " + p.returncode)
    return output
```

And I get an UnicodeDecodeError in the line `output, error = p.communicate()`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\threading.py", line 921, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\threading.py", line 869, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 1170, in _readerthread
    buffer.append(fh.read())
  File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 27: character maps to <undefined>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: unrelated: you don't need `p.stdin.write(input)`; use `... = p.communicate(input)` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`univeral_newlines=True` enables text mode. The subprocess output (bytes) is decoded using `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` character encoding as [@cdosborn mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29548914/4279).

If it doesn't work, provide the actual `encoding` that is used by `command`. And/or specify the error handler such as [`'ignore'`,`'surrogateescape'`, etc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#error-handlers)  as `errors` parameter:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def __executeCommand(self, command: str, input: str = None, 
                     encoding=None, errors='strict') -> str:
    text_mode = (encoding is None)
    with Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdin=PIPE,
               universal_newlines=text_mode) as p:
        if input is not None and not text_mode:
            input = input.encode(encoding, errors) # convert to bytes
        output, err = p.communicate(input)
    if err or p.returncode != 0: 
        raise EnvironmentError("Could not generate the key. "
                               "Error: {}, Return Value: {}".format(
                                   ascii(err), p.returncode))
    return output if text_mode else output.decode(encoding, errors)
```

Comment: I didn't find the right encoding... but as only the error messages contained special characters `output.decode(encoding, errors='replace')` did it for me.

Comment: Python is supposed to be a scripting language... this feels like the worst of C...

Comment: @ChristopherOezbek : how would you implement  the same functionality  in *any* language of your choosing? (There could be a question about how reasonable it is to pack the functionality into a single function but it is unrelated to Python: you can write FORTRAN in any language)

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: Sorry about my frustration, I just have never worked with a scripting language that lets me worry about so many things (encoding, newlines), when I just want plain and simple backtick operator behavior: Run a command, get stdout and stderr as strings for printing to stdout again.

Comment: @ChristopherOezbek: if you need "backtick"; use `output = subprocess.check_output(command)`. I don't see how it is related to the question or Python in general: if you are working with text; you should know about encodings ([There Ain't No Such Thing as Plain Text](http://blog.codinghorror.com/there-aint-no-such-thing-as-plain-text/)).

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: I guess I just need to wrap my head around Python some more. check_output seemed strange to me to explore, because it throws rather than returning std_out, std_err and returncode. When throwing on an error, I could not figure out how to get to output, so I gave up on it and returned to Popen. I figured out the decode in binary mode to deal with encoding, and then switched on universal_newlines because `communicate` did give me newlines that did not print. This blew up my encoding code, leading me to this bug. It should not be this hard.

Comment: @ChristopherOezbek:  the issue is probably that you don't know the difference between an object and its text representation (`repr(obj)`). For example, if you print a `bytes` object with a newline; you get `b'..\n..'`. If the bytes represent text; you should decode them into Unicode using an appropriate character encoding (otherwise you may get a mojibake). If the bytes represent binary data; use binary API e.g., open files in a binary mode, use `sys.stdout.buffer`, etc. I agree: `universal_newlines=True` is a non-intuitive spelling for `text_mode=True` (otherwise the API can be justified).

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Python 3.6 or later, you can fix the error by changing this line:

```
p = sub.Popen(command, stdout=sub.PIPE, stderr=sub.PIPE, stdin=sub.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
```

to this:

```
p = sub.Popen(command, stdout=sub.PIPE, stderr=sub.PIPE, stdin=sub.PIPE, encoding="utf-8", universal_newlines=True)
```

I used UTF-8 above, but you can substitute it with whatever encoding you need.

Answer (score 2):

The `universal_newlines=true` setting results in an additional encoding that is the source of your error.

```
def __executeCommand(self, command: str, input: str = None) -> str:
    p = sub.Popen(command, stdout=sub.PIPE, stderr=sub.PIPE, stdin=sub.PIPE)
    output, error = p.communicate(input)
    if (len(errors) > 0):
        raise EnvironmentError("Could not generate the key: " + error)
    elif (p.returncode != 0):
        raise EnvironmentError("Could not generate the key. Return Value: " + p.returncode)
    return output
```

`universal_newlines=true` results in an encoding based on the output of:

`python -c 'import locale; print locale.getpreferredencoding()'`

Python threw an error when it expected your input to match the encoding above, but instead processed a byte clearly in a different encoding.

More info about python 3.4 `universal_newlines` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments).

Comment: notice: `-> str` in the function signature. If you remove `universal_newlines=True` then `subprocess` works in binary mode i.e., the result is `bytes`, not `str`. You have to decode manually (you need to know the character encoding used by `command`, to decode its output). And you have to encode `input` too.

Comment: I think that must be assumed a layer above. There is no way to know in advance what the encoding of each `command` takes as input or returns as output. From what I know there is no distinction between type bytes and type str. Optionally the output could be wrapped as `str(output, locale.getpreferredencoding())`.

Comment: Wrapping as I mentioned would also likely raise the error mentioned above.

Comment: notice that OP uses Python 3: `str `(Unicode text) is very different from `bytes` type (binary type).

Comment: wrapping *using `locale` encoding* won't help, otherwise universal_newlines would have worked. OP should provide a correct encoding and/or use `errors` handler (`bytestring.decode(encoding, errors)` or via `io.TextIOWrapper(p.stdout, encoding, errors)`)

Answer (score 0):

One my users was running my code that ran the `tasklist` command on Windows. To fix this error I had to use the iso-8859-2 encoding.

```py
p = sub.Popen(cmd, stdout=sub.PIPE, stdin=sub.PIPE, stderr=sub.PIPE,
              text=True, encoding='iso-8859-2')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.