# UnicodeDecodeError when trying to read file object returned by os.popen()

Tags: python, windows

I am trying to make a ping sweeper in Python 3.5.2, but when I try to read the file object os.popen() returns I get an UnicodeDecodeError:

```
  File "C:\Python35\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 18: character maps to <undefined>
```

I am using a german version Windows 10 x64 and in the output of the ping command are various 'ü's, which I think are the problem. I was not able to find a way to choose the encoding to use for the returned object.

Interestingly everything works just fine with Python 2.7.12, so there must have changed something in the decoding.

Comment: `import codecs`

`codecs.open('file_in_question.format, 'r', encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: Won't work.
`response = codecs.open(response, 'r', encoding = 'utf-8')
  File "C:\Python35\lib\codecs.py", line 895, in open
    file = builtins.open(filename, mode, buffering)
TypeError: invalid file: <os._wrap_close object at 0x00000274949A70F0>`

Comment: Show us the rest of the error stack, including the line in *your* program that starts the error.

Comment: `Scanning in progress...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ping_sweep_th.py", line 51, in <module>
    thread.run()
  File "ping_sweep_th.py", line 27, in run
    run1(self.start, self.end)
  File "ping_sweep_th.py", line 35, in run1
    for line in response:
  File "C:\Python35\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 18: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: I think the standard solution to this issue with python 3 is passing `universal_newlines=True` to Popen, although [this can be erroneous too](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29546311/5067311).

Comment: That is not possible - I am using os.popen.

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad...

Comment: There's no consistent locale in Windows command-line programs. When writing to a pipe a program might use the OEM codepage, ANSI codepage, current console output codepage, UTF-16LE, or UTF-8. You have to know ahead of time what codepage it uses and look for an option to force unicode output (usually that's UTF-16LE) like the /U option of cmd.exe (for its internal commands) or the /unicode option of robocopy.exe.

Comment: If you're using `subprocess.Popen`, the `universal_newlines` option assumes ANSI (e.g. 1252 in a Western locale), which will often be wrong. In that case you need to manually wrap the binary-mode `stdout` with an `io.TextIOWrapper`.

Comment: In 3.x `os.open` is implemented by calling `proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=buffering)` and then returning `_wrap_close(io.TextIOWrapper(proc.stdout), proc)`. So you're getting the default encoding for `io.TextIOWrapper`, which is ANSI (i.e. `locale.getpreferredencoding()`).

Comment: I was not able to find such an option for ping.exe, and when I used 'cmd.exe /u /k ping -n 1 127.0.0.1' as command for os.popen it did not work either - I even got another error from the shell itself telling me twice that  a process tried to write to a non-existent pipe. I also tried using subprocess.Popen but I was not able to fix it using that way either (same error, with and without universal_newlines).

Comment: I successfully managed to replace os.`popen` with `subprocess.Popen` and then just read from the `stdout` attribute: `response = subprocess.Popen(comm, shell = True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE).stdout
  for line in response.readlines(): [...]`